# Logging as [Tenant 1] when mult-itenancy is disabled

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Is it expected behavior to log in as Default Tenant, and not Host, when multi-tenancy is disabled?

Doesn't it make more sense to work only with HOST when multi-tenancy is disabled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a design choice. For the minimum code change to cover both multi-tenant and no tenant applications ABP uses the default tenant (1).

So answer is; yes expected behaviour.